# Page counter resets at each included file

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, input, standalone

I am writing a thesis that consists of 4 stand alone documents which are united in a master document in different chapters with `\input`. For this purpose, I use the standalone package. The problem is the page numbering restarts from 1 at every Chapter/Input both at the pages and in the TOC. **Any idea how to fix this?** The master doc looks like:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1.5in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{standalone}% Need standalone package

\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\abstractname{Abstract}  %%% here
\makeatletter
\if@titlepage
\newenvironment{abstract}{%
    \titlepage
    \null\vfil
    \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
    \begin{center}%
        \bfseries \abstractname
        \@endparpenalty\@M
    \end{center}}%
    {\par\vfil\null\endtitlepage}
    \else
    \newenvironment{abstract}{%
        \if@twocolumn
        \section*{\abstractname}%
        \else
        \small
        \begin{center}%
            {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
        \end{center}%
        \quotation
        \fi}
    {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
    \fi
    \makeatother

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{authblk}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black
}

\title{Title}


\begin{document}
    \maketitle  
\tableofcontents


\chapter*{Non-Technical Summary}
\markboth{Non-Technical Summary}{Non-Technical Summary}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Non-Technical Summary}  
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{1}  
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{2} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{3} 

\input{Summary.tex}

\chapter{1}
\input{"1"}

\chapter{2}
\input{"2"}

\chapter{3}
\input{"3"}

\bibliography{bibl}


\end{document}
```

**Edit:** The "Summary.tex" is the following, and the other files are with similar structure:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1.5in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\fontsize{15}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 

\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{authblk}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black
}

\title{T}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \newpage
    \section*{Abstract}
    \newpage
    \section*{A}
    \newpage
    \section{B}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) [Do you need `summary.tex` for the example? Do you need all the packages for the example?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) How do `1.tex`, `2.tex`, `3.tex` and `4.tex` look?

Comment: In LaTeX you would normally use `\include{filename}` rather than `\input filename` (in your not-so-minimal working example, `\input{"filename"}` looks really wrong!:). As to your  problem, it seems that you are using `standalone`. I haven't used this but I think that in order to get page numbers etc right you have to compile the main document at least once to get all of the page numbers right. The behavior that your are describing shouldn't happen by default so it must be something that you are doing or not doing. Are you only compiling the component documents separately?

Comment: If i understand the question correctly, you are either screwing up because of highly overcomplicating a simple issue, or just doing it wrong. Why don't you just have *one* document, *i.e.* a *single* `\documentclass`  line?